# angular material 6 multiple mat-sliders with different colors

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

i have 3 'mat-slider's in a page and i want to have 3 different colors for the sliders. i cant override the theme colors for the page(component) as it will apply to all the sliders. do i have to make 3 different components for the sliders and override theme colors in each? what is the easiest way to achieve this?
below are my angular and package versions,

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.3.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.16
@angular/material                 6.3.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: can't you simply use css?

Comment: doesn't work. somehow they are not applied and theme color used. only overriding theme colors with "::ng-deep" worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best way but as you ask for the easiest way here is a solution.

Give each slider a class:

```
// home.component.hmtl
<mat-slider class="mat-slide-1"></mat-slider>
<mat-slider class="mat-slide-2"></mat-slider>
<mat-slider class="mat-slide-3"></mat-slider>
```

In your styles.scss reference these classes and in each class define the element you wish to change the colour of and make it important:

```
// styles.scss
.mat-slide-1 {
    .mat-slider-thumb {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
}

.mat-slide-2 {
    .mat-slider-thumb {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
}

.mat-slide-3 {
    .mat-slider-thumb {
        background-color: green !important;
    }
}
```

This example only changes the colour of the thumb but inspect the elements of the slider to find the class relevant to the element you want to change.

[image]

A more correct solution would be using multiple themes and applying them separately to each component. Refer the [material docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why the styles doesn't work when used in component.css ?

Comment: Its to do with Angular's view encapsulation at run time: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles.
If the answer worked for you, can you accept it so others can reference it, thanks.