# Angular Mat-Slider Customization

Tags: angular

1. Changing the thumb label color dynamically
2. track-fill color change dynamically
3. show thumb label and ticks continuously
4. increase the height of the slider
5. make ticks more thick
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat old post, but I can answer your first question, as I had to figure it out on my own, there was no SO help:

**Changing the thumb label color dynamically**

You have to put below code into the styles.scss:

```
    .mat-slider-thumb-label {
       background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Then you can manipulate this scss setting from ts file dynamically, as you would do otherwise:

[Change styles.scss dynamically in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952475/change-styles-scss-dynamically-in-angular)

If you would like to customize several sliders in one component, you can refer to below question:

[angular material 6 multiple mat-sliders with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038736/angular-material-6-multiple-mat-sliders-with-different-colors)